# Let $f:[-\frac 12,2]\to R$ and $g: [-\frac 12,2] \to R$ be defined as $f(x)=[x^2-3]$ and $g(x)=|x|f(x)+|4x-7|f(x)$

Tags: derivatives, continuity

> CONT
> Let $f:[-\frac 12,2]\to R$ and $g: [-\frac 12,2] \to R$ be defined as $f(x)=[x^2-3]$ and $g(x)=|x|f(x)+|4x-7|f(x)$. Find the number of points of non differentiability of $g(x)$

The points we need to check for are $0,1,\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3, 2, \frac 74$

I don’t really know the proper way to do this, but instinctually $1,\sqrt 3, \sqrt 2$ will be the correc points.

By computation, I proved that the function is differentiable at $x=\frac 74$

In $g(x)$, the first term is non differentiable at $x=0$ but the second term isn’t, so the function *should* be non differentiable at $0$ (Emphasis on should because the grap shows that the function is continuous and differentiable at $x=0$)

I can’t speak for $2$, because the function is continuous over that point, but I don’t if extremes are counted in differentiability

Is my answer correct?